# Connecting to any IMAP using Javamail

Tags: java, imap, jakarta-mail

I am trying to connect to IMAP using Javamail Api. I can successfully connect to Gmail by this code but cannot connect to my university id.

```
public class MailConnection {
    Folder inbox;

public MailConnection() throws MessagingException{
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
     try{
         Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
         Store store = session.getStore("imap");
         store.connect("mailbox.xyz.com", "emailId@xyz.com", "password");
         System.out.println(store);

         inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
         System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + inbox.getUnreadMessageCount());
     }
     catch (NoSuchProviderException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
     }
}
```

When i use my Uni id i get the following error message -

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: * BYE ;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.iap.ConnectionException: * BYE 
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:668)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at MailConnection.<init>(MailConnection.java:21)
    at MailConnection.main(MailConnection.java:34)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.ConnectionException: * BYE 
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.processGreeting(Protocol.java:223)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.processGreeting(IMAPProtocol.java:228)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:120)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:111)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:637)
    ... 4 more
```

I dont know what is going wrong here. What does this BYE signify? How to fix this?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you uni uses IMAP and not SMTP only?

Comment: the incoming server is IMAP and the outgoing server is SMTP

Comment: Sorry i meant pop3 not smtp

Comment: ya it's IMAP.... coz i configured it in Outlook as well

Comment: BYE is the protocol message that says the server is closing connection.  It seems to be saying BYE as soon as you connect.  Perhaps there's some rule that only allows connection from certain places?

Comment: it actually gets stuck a bit and after around 20-30 secs it throws these errors. I can normally connect to that mail using the browser but not through Javamail api

Comment: The browser isn't using IMAP.  Turn on [session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and post all the debug output.  You probably need to enable SSL or STARTTLS.  See the [package javadocs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html) for the properties.

Comment: after turning on session debugging i get                         DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.5
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG: trying to connect to host "mailbox.xyz.com", port 143, isSSL false
* BYE - and then the same error as above

Comment: After setting this -     props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
      props.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true"); I get PKIX path building failed. :(

Comment: I follow this - https://blogs.oracle.com/gc/entry/unable_to_find_valid_certification but on executing the program java InstallCert mailbox.xyz.com i get No Errors, certificate is already trusted.